# Is this sequence increasing or decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question came up in a university entrance exam of mine: Is $\tfrac{2^n}{n!}$ where $n$ is a positive integer

1. Increasing
2. Decreasing
3. Increases then decreases
4. Decreases then increases

I would've used the derivative rule, but I'm unsure on how to take the derivative of a factorial; I just put in the number from 1 to 5 and saw that value decreases as $n$ increased, so I marked it as decreasing? Is this answer correct? If not, could you clarify on how to approach this question. Thank you.

Comment: If $a_n = \tfrac{2^n}{n!}$ then $$a_{n+1} = \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{2}{n+1} \cdot \frac{2^n}{n!} = \frac{2}{n+1} a_n \leq a_n.$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution has been provided in the comment.

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{2}{n+1}a_n$$

For $n=1, a_{n+1}=a_n$.

For $n>1, a_{n+1}<a_n$.

---

Now, notice that $a_1=\frac{2}{1}=2$.

$a_2=\frac{2}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{1}=2$.

$a_3=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{1}$

and so on. While the numerator of the multiplier is fixed to be $2$, the denominator is $n+1$ which grows and more than $2$ once $n>1$, and hence it is decreasing for $n>1$.